# pytorch for gpu installation error on ubuntu 14.04(cuda 8.0, python2.7.6, pip 19.0.1) - wheel not supported

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I follow the tutorial command on pytorch site, but such errors came out.

> > error: torch-1.0.0-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.

I used following commands for installation.

```
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Show the results of following commands: `python --version`, `pip --version`, `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`. The error might be because of incompatible versions.

Comment: Python 2.7.6

pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Linux heejae 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
heejae@heejae:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: since i installed tensorflow, cudnn for python2.7, i cannot change the version of python...

Comment: sometimes this kind of error comes out ...Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='download.pytorch.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'),))

Answer (score 0):

The *wheel* is a ZIP archive with the .whl extension that should have a specially formatted file name and contain a relocatable Python package to be recognized on your platform.

Please use your web browser such as Firefox to obtain *manylinux1* wheels [directly from PyPI website](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files):

> torch-1.0.1.post2-cp27-cp27**m**-*manylinux1*_x86_64.whl (582.6 MB)
>   torch-1.0.1.post2-cp27-cp27**mu**-*manylinux1*_x86_64.whl (582.5 MB) <= try this one

Please make sure to choose one appropriate for your specific OS/platform. In your case, the `mu-manylinux1` is the most likely choice. You could use this shell command to ensure:

`$ python -c "import sys; print 'UCS4/UTF-32: mu-manylinux1' if sys.maxunicode > 65535 else 'UCS2/UTF-16: m-manylinux1'"`
Python 3 version:
`$ python3 -c "import sys; print('UCS4/UTF-32: mu-manylinux1' if sys.maxunicode > 65535 else 'UCS2/UTF-16: m-manylinux1')"`

**mu** is more common and means that your Python stores Unicode data in UCS-4 (UTF-32) format.
**cp27** stands for Python 2.7; likewise cp36 is for Python 3.6
**x86_64** is for 64-bit platform. Pytorch doesn't support 32-bit..

All manylinux1 wheels require pip v8.1 or later to be `pip install`'ed  (you have v19.0.1 - ok).

Regarding the `SSLError...sslv3 alert handshake failure` you've mentioned in the comment, it's caused by the fact that `pip` doesn't use old SSL/TLS protocols to connect to PyPI since about a year ago, but your system's underlying OpenSSL library is outdated, and Python 2.7.6 `ssl` module doesn't support the required TLS 1.2 protocol anyway. I will address this issue in your [another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413685/insecureplatform-warning).