# Insecureplatform warning

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to install pytorch on ubuntu 14.04, and i am using python 2.7.6/ cuda 8.0. But error comes out.

error 1:

```
torch-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

error 2:

```
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'),)': /whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='download.pytorch.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'),))
```

I found that Insecureplatformwarning always appeared whenever i tried to install new modules. Is it possible to solve this problem without changing version of python or cuda? Since i am using tensorflow1.3.0 for python 2.7 and cuda 8.0, I am reluctant to change the version of python or cuda.

Comment: The second error is due to an outdated SSL module. Upgrade it using `pip install -U pyopenssl`

Answer (score 0):

The first issue of the unsupported pytorch wheel is addressed in detail in the [related posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54358292/9575715) specific to your case. Please try torch-1.0.1.post2-cp27-cp27**mu-manylinux1**_x86_64.whl (582.5 MB) downloadable via web browser from the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files) website.

About the `SSLError...sslv3 alert handshake failure`, the error suggests that your operating system's OpenSSL library version<`1.0.1` and Python version<`2.7.9` do not support the newer [TLS protocol version 1.2](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html) that `pip` requires to connect to PyPI since [about a year ago](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html).
You can check the system OpenSSL library version with:
    `$ python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)" && openssl version`

Even if the openssl library was up-to-date, another problem is that Python version 2.7.6 itself has `ssl` module that doesn't support PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, which needs Python versions 2.7.9+ (or 3.4+) or later. In Ubuntu, the Python 2.7.9 version first appeared in Vivid Vervet (15.04) and Python 3.4 - since 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn), while current 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) ships 2.7.14+ and 3.6.4+ respectively.

> " > Is it possible to solve this problem without changing version of python or cuda? "

Fortunately, yes, to fix it you can install several Python wheels (packages) manually -- the detailed step-by-step guide is [available here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646558).

Specifically, the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/) manylinux1 [wheel](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files) contains the most recent statically-linked OpenSSL library that will re-enable `pip` (versions 10+) and will allow you to continue to use your good old Ubuntu linux with new Python programs.